# FSharp and Microsoft Office PIA

Tags: f#, ms-office

I am using the Microsoft Office PIA from FSharp.  When I try and get the SynonymInfo from Microsoft Word like this:

```
#r "Office.dll"
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll"
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

let application = ApplicationClass()
let synonymInfo = application.SynonymInfo("bracket")
let meaningList = synonymInfo.MeaningList :?> string[]
```

I am getting this exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Is the casting from the COM object causing this?  How can I cast this correctly?  Is the * for a tuple?  If so string[,] also does not work...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Office interop returns an array where the index does not start from 0 but (probably) from 1 (good old Visual Basic times!) This is what the `*` means in the type `String[*]`.

You can even create such arrays from F#:

```
let array = System.Array.CreateInstance(typeof<int>, [| 10 |], [| 1 |])
```

Unfortunately, `Int32[*]` is a different type than `Int32[]` and so the casting fails:

```
// System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast 
// object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.
array :?> int[]
```

You'll need to convert the data in the 1-indexed array to some other structure in another way. The type of `array` in my example implements non-generic `IEnumerable`, so you should be able to write something like:

```
array |> Seq.cast<int> |> Array.ofSeq
```

If the type of the value in your case is `obj`, you'll need to cast it to the interface first:

```
(thing :?> IEnumerable) |> Seq.cast<string> |> Array.ofSeq
```

You can also get an array with index-value pairs using something like this:

```
[| for i in array.GetLowerBound(0) .. array.GetUpperBound(0) ->
     i, array.GetValue(i) :?> int |]
```